# Issue - IMEI - HTC Flyer Tab [Telephony Manager]

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have HTC Flyer tab with version Android 2.3.4. I am not able to retrieve the IMEI number through TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(). It always return null.

Can somebody try to read out the IMEI on another device. I would like to know whether it is a Google or HTC problem.

This is a 'GSM' device. And it is brand new, didn't have any OS update.

FYI,
Included Manifest:

My programs on sumsung galaxy, Motorola xoom, and all smartphones working well.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the tab devices do not have IMEI number. You can get WI-FI MAC address of the device.

```
WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
String ID = wifiInf.getMacAddress();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting null with `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()`, use

```
Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

for example:

```
final TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
AndroidDeviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId();
}
else{
AndroidDeviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
}
```

even `ANDROID_ID` is not secure to use:

> More specifically, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID. This is a 64-bit
>   quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots. It
>   is reset when the device is wiped.
>
> ANDROID_ID seems a good choice for a unique device identifier. There
>   are downsides: First, it is not 100% reliable on releases of Android
>   prior to 2.2 (“Froyo”). Also, there has been at least one
>   widely-observed bug in a popular handset from a major manufacturer,
>   where every instance has the same ANDROID_ID.

but i recommed use this method suggested in Android Developer´s Blog: [Identifying App Installations](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html):

```
public class Installation {
    private static String sID = null;
    private static final String INSTALLATION = "INSTALLATION";

    public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
        if (sID == null) {  
            File installation = new File(context.getFilesDir(), INSTALLATION);
            try {
                if (!installation.exists())
                    writeInstallationFile(installation);
                sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return sID;
    }

    private static String readInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        f.readFully(bytes);
        f.close();
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    private static void writeInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        out.write(id.getBytes());
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class SystemProperties = null;
        SystemProperties = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");

        //Parameters Types
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class[] paramTypes = new Class[1];
        paramTypes[0] = String.class;

        Method get=null;
        get = SystemProperties.getMethod("get", paramTypes);


        //Parameters
        Object[] params = new Object[1];
        params[0] = new String("ro.gsm.imei");

        IMEI = (String) get.invoke(SystemProperties, params);
```

Comment: are you sure the method can get the imei in all device?